# PowerShell start a process remotely doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I want to start a process on a remote server as the "test" user, but it just doesn't work and I can't find out why.

```
$PW = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String 'XXXX'
$CRED = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "domain\test", $PW
$Server = new-pssession -computername ServerName -credential $CRED

Invoke-Command -session $Server -ScriptBlock {
    $APP = "C:\test\app.exe"
    if ((Get-Process -Name app -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
        write-host "not running" 
        Start-Process -FilePath $APP
    }
    else {
        write-host "running"
    }
}

Remove-PSSession $Server
```

If I RDP into the remote server and run the code directly, it will launch the application, but If I run the code through my machine with `Invoke-Command`, it doesn't launch anything.

I was trying to see the process happening on remote server through RDP, but nothing happened. This application must be running under a specific user "test" which I used in the script and RDP session.

The remote server is Win2012R2 and PSversion is 4.0

PSversion on my machine is 5.1

Comment: Have to ask, have you followed the instrucations listed at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Yes, the first thing to do is to enable psremoting.... lol

Comment: OK..  Outside of Powershell, what about using PSRemote from PStools to run your app on the server/system in question? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools

Comment: Tired as well, failed. I think the issue maybe is about that if this app supports running remotely or only locally.

Comment: Are you looking to see the application run interactively (e.g. launch a window) or is something that can be run non-interactive (e.g. in the background)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start an interactive application with psremoting.

Answer (score 0):

After all kind of tests, looks like there is no way to start this application through PSrmoting.

My solution to this is

1) Using "Autologon.exe" from PSTools to login as desired user after reboot.

2) Schedule to run this application upon user login in TaskScheduler.

Works well .